# How to build multiple tasks in Grunt js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs

I'm new to grunt js. I'm trying to build multiple tasks with grunt js but each time i got error. How to out from this issue?
Here's the my example code.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        useminPrepare:{
            html:['app/index.html'],
            options:{
                dest:'build'
            }
        },
        usemin:{html:['build/index.html']},
        copy:{
            task0: {
                src:['app/index.html', 'app/index2.html'],
                dest:['build/index.html', 'build/index2.html']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');

    grunt.registerTask('build',[
        'copy:task0',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'usemin'
    ])
}
```

Comment: what s the error.. post that too..

Comment: what command are u runinng?

Comment: try to run `grunt build --stack`, and post the output

Comment: its showing ' object build/index.html, build/index2.html has no method 'replace' '... @vlio20

Comment: `dest` shouldn't be an array, it should be your a string of the destination

Comment: vlio20 is right. Always check the docs for tasks https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples

Answer (score 1):

From the little information you provided, I am guessing that you are running `grunt build`.

I can see that you are missing some tasks definition as one of the answers points out, but also `dest` attribute should be a string. You can see it in the documentation: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples

Here is example for your case:

```
        copy:{
            task0: {
                src:['app/index.html', 'app/index2.html'],
                dest: 'build/'
            }
        }
```

note that the missing tasks are: `concat, cssmin, uglify`

Comment: Nice observation on the `dest` issue. I have a feeling both our answers eventually solve the _multiple_ issues here

Comment: Again i got an error folks. syntaxerror:unexpected token.

Comment: please do it with `--stack` flag and post

Comment: What i have posted above, that one.. @vlio20

Comment: Nope, you didn't removed the array of the dest under the copy task

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi-colon after `registerTask`, should be:

```
grunt.registerTask('build',[
    'copy:task0',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Comment: "missing" semi-colons are [often not a problem at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)